# Gitlab CI node_modules issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two pipelines with two jobs, one job is to install my npm packages, and the other is to bundle and deploy. I have one pipeline that is running on master when I do merge requests and another pipeline that is triggered via webhooks. My merge requests works fine but the webhook does not, and I have noticed the following difference:

In my merge requests my npm package is installing and finding all of the necessary packages / files but in my webhook trigger even though it’s using the same commit and branch it doesn’t seem to be installing all of the packages.

[Image with all packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKVQb.png)

[Image where it seems it’s not installing the same number of packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdTh6.png)

Is there a reason why this us happening even though they are in the same branch and using the same commit but one is a merge request while the other is a pipeline trigger? Is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Below is the job that is failing

```
production_publish:
  stage: publish
  before_script:
    - npm config set registry https://npm.ef.com/
    - npm config set //npm.ef.com/:_authToken ${EF_NPM_TOKEN}
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run bundle
    - node ./devops/deployStatic
  only:
    refs:
      - pipelines
      - master
    variables:
      - $NODE_ENV == "production"
  except:
    refs:
      - staging
      - pushes
      - merge_requests
  tags:
    - storyblok
    - prod
```

Below is the job that is working fine

```
install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm config set registry https://npm.ef.com/
    - npm config set //npm.ef.com/:_authToken ${EF_NPM_TOKEN}
    - npm install
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-${CI_JOB_NAME}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 mos
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  except:
    refs:
      - triggers
      - staging
  tags:
    - storyblok
    - prod

e1_id_production_deploy_next_server:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - export COMMIT_TIME=$(git show -s --format=%ct $CI_COMMIT_SHA)
    - export COMMIT_TAG=$(git show -s --format=%H $CI_COMMIT_TAG)
    - export PRODUCT=$(echo $CI_JOB_NAME | cut -d '_' -f 1)
    - export REGION=$(echo $CI_JOB_NAME | cut -d '_' -f 2)
    - export NODE_ENV=$(echo $CI_JOB_NAME | cut -d '_' -f 3)
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip
  script:
    - npm run build
    - zip ./builds/server_build_$COMMIT_TAG.zip -rq * .[^.]* .next/\* -x out/\* -x .git/\*
    - node ./devops/deployServer
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  except:
    - triggers
  tags:
    - storyblok
    - prod
  dependencies:
    - install
```

The main problem again is in the npm install for both cases, for the first one it doesn't seem to be installing all of my packages. Thanks ahead of time for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the main issue was in certain packages being set in the devDependencies.

1. Our staging environment was working fine because NODE_ENV is not set to production
2. Our master environment that was set in 2 jobs was working because we were actually setting the NODE_ENV after the npm install (in the second job). In the other job the NODE_ENV was being set before npm install and when NODE_ENV=production npm install does not install devDependencies
3. Fix was to add the packages required from devDependencies as dependencies

Comment: There is also one possibility you did not mentioned, The number of cache files will be inconsistency if you don't have package-lock.json and clean installation (`npm ci`).